# Cann't Access NFC Card in SDK on windows 7

Tags: nfc

I have ACR122U reader and Mifare1k card, When I try sdk on windows 7 It's can't access the card, But XP It's can.(XP test in VMware)

result in Mifare Programming(SDK Project)

- I can Initialize and get Reader name but I can't Connect the card.(on Windows 7)

> `Program ready`
>   `?`
>   `?`
>
> When I try on XP I can get Reader name, connect card, load authen key and authen key.
>
> > `Program ready`
> >     `Successful connection to ACR122 0`
> >     `<FF 82 00 00 06 FF FF FF FF FF FF`
> >     `>90 00`
> >     `<FF 86 00 00 05 01 00 00 61 01`
> >     `>90 00`
> >     `Authentication success!`  
> >     
> >     *in ACR122UTool(application come with sdk),It's not sdk, but It's can send Direct command and got a result.(run on windows 7)
> >
> > > `ACR122U PICC Interface`
> > >       `Connected to :  ACS ACR122 0`
> > >       `ACR122U APDU Command`
> > >       `< FF 82 00 00 06 FF FF FF FF FF FF`
> > >       `> 90 00`
> > >       `ACR122U APDU Command`
> > >       `< FF 86 00 00 05 01 00 00 61 01`
> > >       `> 90 00`

I don't understand, code from sdk can't access the card but application come with sdk can access the card and read write to card(run on windows 7)

PM. Sorry for my Eng (-_-")

Comment: Sorry for my first post ^^", i'm formatting answer new right now.

Comment: I believe this question belongs to superuser.com. You will probably get morr help there. Good luck.

Comment: update my solution, I'm found error on vs2008 and when i move code to vs2010, it's can